# PHP mail не работает

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, с php посылкой сообщений на почту пользователей. Не получается послать, хотя возвращается true. Код примерно такой

```
$mail = mail("user@mail.ru","Hello","Text");
if($mail = true)
echo "message Sended";
```

Этот кусок взят из примера в мануале и в принципе простой до полного одубения, но не работает, может подскажете почему? Буду благодарен!

Сайт не локальный, а на хостинге.

Comment: Может сообщение таки отправляется и просто попадают в спам?

Если нет - есть ли ошибки php?

И вообще - что именно вы делали, как проверяли?

Comment: как проверял? я посадил код на сайт хостера там пишется что все труе (по словам авторов мануала это значит что все должно работать )
но письмо на доходит

Comment: Как вы проверяли что письмо, цитирую - "на доходит"?

И таки да - если результат `mail()` истина - значит письмо доставлено (во всяком случае все что зависело от PHP - выполнено)

Comment: не доходит я ошибся буквой  вы когда нибудь писали код посылающий сообщения пользователям ? 
Здесь кажется никто не может помочь

Comment: Да писал и, не редко, это сообщение попадает в спам

Теоретически может даже блокироваться... (это исключительно предположение)

Comment: Надо смотреть логи почты (sendmail или что там у хостера).

Еще вариант - создать файл  с текстом и отправить его вызвав команду mail (у Вас ведь \*nix ?).

Comment: Ну на хостинге скорее всего *nix, поэтому это вариант.

Суть в том что помочь вам не могут исключительно потому, что, к сожалению, программист экстрасенс - редкое явление =)

Answer (score 3):

```
$mail['charset'] = "windows-1251";
$mail['to'] = ""; // Кому
$mail['from'] = ""; // От кого
$mail['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];
$mail['massage'] = $_POST['massage'];

$mail['header'] = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
."From: " . $mail['from'] . "\n"
."X-Priority: 3\n"
."X-Mailer: Mailer\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
."Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $mail['charset'] . "\n";

mail ($mail['to'], $mail['subject'], $mail['massage'], $mail['header']);
```

Попробуйте этот код использовать! Если глухо, значит проблемы с хостером!

Comment: А почему массаж ( `$mail['massage']` ) ?)

Comment: исключительно для красивости)

Comment: Друзья всем ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо за то что решили помочь но оказывается простая пересылка сообщения требует платного хостинга и причем в тестовом периоде они отключают эту службу в php.ini 
я начинающий  php-шник и не знаю как правильно написать наверняка а хотелось бы проверить правильно ли работает((