# Форма обратной связи на сайт

Tags: php, html

Форма не отправляет данные с сайта на почту timeweb

index.php

```
<section class="form">
    <div class="w-container">
        <div class="title"><h2 class="white">Текст</h2></div>
        <form class="form-block" action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <div class="b3-form">
                <div class="wrap-i"><input class="form-el" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required></div>
                <div class="wrap-i"><input class="form-el" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required></div>
                <div class="wrap-i"><input class="form-el" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required></div>
            </div>
             <input type="submit" class="form_submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

mail.php

```
<? 
    // ----------------------------конфигурация-------------------------- // 

    $adminemail="info@frinstar1.ru";  // e-mail админа         
    $date=date("d.m.y"); // число.месяц.год   
    $time=date("H:i"); // часы:минуты:секунды    
    $backurl="http://frinstar1.ru";  // На какую страничку переходит после отправки письма 

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------- // 

    // Принимаем данные с формы    
    $name=$_POST['name'];    
    $email=$_POST['email'];     
    $msg=$_POST['message']; 

    // Проверяем валидность e-mail  
    if (!preg_match("|^([a-z0-9_\.\-]{1,20})@([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,20})\.([a-z]{2,4})|is", 
    strtolower($email))) 
    { 
        echo "<center>Вернитесь <a href='javascript:history.back(1)'<B>назад</B></a>. Вы 
    указали неверные данные!";      
    }     
    else {      
      $msg="<p>Имя: $name</p>
            <p>E-mail: $email</p>       
            <p>Сообщение: $msg</p>"; 

      // Отправляем письмо админу       
      mail("$adminemail", "$date $time Сообщение от $name", "$msg"); 

      // Выводим сообщение пользователю 
     print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 6000); 
     //--></script>      
     $msg      
     <p>Сообщение отправлено! Подождите, сейчас вы будете перенаправлены на главную страницу...</p>";  
     exit; 

   } 
?>
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код. Проверяйте что возвращает функция `mail`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP mail не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70802/php-mail-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)